# Running wmplayer.exe in Python

Tags: python

I am looking to run wmplayer in python but can't get the syntax correct.  The following allows me to play a file using `wmplayer.exe`.  E.g.

```
start /d "ProgramFiles(x86)\Windows Media Player" wmplayer.exe e:\Python\escapeVR\videos\screen_sav1.webm
```

I'm stuck trying to put this as an os call E.g.

```
os.system("start /d "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\\Windows Media Player" wmplayer.exe e:\\Python\\escapeVR\\videos\\screen_sav1.webm)
```

Causes a SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Suggestions, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape all backslashes and double quotes:

```
os.system("start /d \"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\\Windows Media Player\" wmplayer.exe e:\\Python\\escapeVR\\videos\\screen_sav1.webm")
```

Note that if you do not wish to escape the double quotes, python support single quotes for strings. If you use them, the double quotes inside the string do not need to be escaped:

```
os.system('start /d "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\\Windows Media Player" wmplayer.exe e:\\Python\\escapeVR\\videos\\screen_sav1.webm')
```

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you.  Both are working fine for me.

Comment: Great! Dont forget to validate the answer please, if you consider the issue solved. Thanks!